# Multiple List Comprehensions Or One For Loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

Is it better (in terms of speed and efficiency) to use multiple list comprehensions or a single for loop when adding items from one collection to multiple separate collections, such as in the example(s) provided? Or is there any better solutions?

In the examples, 'data' is a two dimensional array.

Example 1 (For Loop):

```
ids = []
usernames = []
passwords = []

for i in data:
    ids.append(i[0])
    usernames.append(i[1])
    passwords.append(i[2])
```

Example 2 (List Comprehensions):

```
ids = [i[0] for i in data]
usernames = [i[1] for i in data]
passwords = [i[2] for i in data]
```

Comment: You can benchmark both solutions with `timeit`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Comment: As a general rule of thumb in python, prioritize readability over speed.

Comment: If you don't need lists, you might be able to do pretty well with `zip(*data)` here as well.

Comment: You may want to consider to have a single list of custom objects/dataclass that hold all the three values.

Comment: And if you _do_ need lists, can `ids, usernames, passwords = map(list, zip(*data))`